# Disconnect from database and set offline

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2, smo

I'm using Vb.net 2013 , Entity Framework , SQL Server 2008R2 and SMO.
 I want to disconnect from database and set offline.
 I try this code using SMO:

```
 conn = New ServerConnection()
 conn.ServerInstance = "MyServer"
 srv = New Server(conn)
 Dim db As Database
 db = srv.Databases("MyDatabase")
 db.SetOffline
```

But the problem is that the application hang on the last line and doesn't respond.
 Is there anything that I should do with entity framework before set the database offline ?
 Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that SMO's `Database.SetOffline` is the right method to set a database offline. It has no options whatsoever to specify no-wait or to disconnect current users. Of course you can try to make sure EF doesn't keep any open connections to the database (which it shouldn't do by default, so I wonder if this is going on here anyway), but you have no control over any other processes connecting to the database.

I would execute a SQL query against the server connection so you can control what the command should do:

```sql
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET OFFLINE WITH NO_WAIT
```

or

```sql
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

(or `AFTER x SECONDS` in stead of `IMMEDIATE`)

Comment: How can I make sure that EF doesn't keep any open connections ?

Comment: No need to worry about that, unless you deliberately open connections yourself.